# Implement a secured and production ready authentication system in a Node.js server without being tied to a third-party provider

Tags: node.js, authentication

I am used to develop web apps using the Meteor JavaScript framework, which handles authentication. I am now developing for the first time a web app using a Node.js (Express) + GraphQL stack on the backend, with React on the frontend, so I have to handle authentication myself.

I read a lot of things about it, and I like the idea of token based authentication. I am thinking about using JWT, so I don't have to deal with sessions.

I know there are a lot of tutorials, but each one always has a sort of disclaimer like : "this tutorial is not production ready, use it for educational purposes only...". Every time I read something about authentication, it seems to be something so difficult to implement that I shouldn't implement it myself. But I don't want to use services providers like AWS Cognito, Google Cloud Platform because I want to keep my users data in my own system and database. I don't want to be tied to a third party provider.

I know how to generate jwt tokens, refresh tokens, how to verify them, etc... I am able to develop a working auth system, but I am never sure I do it in a secure and production ready way because of all those comments I can read on the Internet.

So, what would you recommend to implement a secured and production ready authentication system in a Node.js server without being tied to a third-party provider. Do you know any complete tutorial or documentation about it?

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic on SO. If you have problems implementing some tutorial or you have doubts that some specific things are suitable for production, feel free to ask more specific questions and make sure you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with your own efforts, because a link to a tutorial isn't enough. *this tutorial is not production ready* - learning why exactly it's not production ready gives you better chances to end up wth a workable solution that looking for a tutorial that doesn't have such disclaimer. There's a bunch of examples of Express+JWT on GH

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure this question is appropriate on SO, but I don't know on what forum it would be?

Comment: Try Quora or Reddit, although digging through real-world setups on GH will give you more than pasting the code from tutorials which can be oversimplified.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to implement authentication for an application.

- Use a identity server manage by you
- Use a fully manage service for authentication.
- Use authentication middleware.
- Write your own authentication solution.

If you are afraid in vender locking I would suggest to use an authentication middleware like [PassportJS](http://www.passportjs.org/) which will facilitate the abstraction of authentication strategy with its implementation.

On the otherhand writing your custom authentication can be challenging in terms of security, specially finding snd fixing these vulnerabilities.

Comment: I've already looked PassportJS, but I didn't really understood what values it brings me as I still have to write my own logic. But you're not the first telling me to use it so I will give it a try again!